# How to remove CTRL-A characters from file using SED?

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I want to remove all "^A" control characters from a file using SED.  I can remove all control characters using 'sed s/[[:cntrl:]]//g' but how can I specify "^A" specifically?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

to reproduce "^A" simply press Ctrl-v Ctrl-a  this will reproduce the ^A in the file

```
sed -i -e 's/^A/BLAH/g' testfile
```

the `^A` in that line is the result of me pressing Ctrl-v Ctrl-a

Comment: I would recommend against doing this, because you won't be able to easily copy and paste it, put it into a script, edit the script with any editor, and so on.

Comment: @Tobia You can do ctrl-v ctrl-a in vi and save the file with the correct ^A in there.  Copy and pasting with the GUI paste buffer is the only thing you can't do.

Answer (score 11):

^A is byte 1 or `\x01` so you should be able to do this:

```
sed 's/\x01//g'
```

Keep in mind that for single-byte changes, "tr" is faster than sed, although you'll have to use bash's `$'..'` syntax to give it a 0x01 byte:

```
tr -d $'\x01'
```

Comment: You can type a literal into a quoted string in Bash by prefixing it with C-v: `tr -d 'C-vC-a'`, where you literally press control-v and then control-a.

Comment: Try using the `$''` in sed too: `sed $'s/\x01//g'`

Comment: You are right.  This does work with sed.  For some reason it does not work on my mac, by it works on ubuntu.

Comment: @DJElbow, Mac has BSD Sed; Ubuntu has GNU Sed.  They have different features.  GNU Sed generally has more features.  If you want Sed commands (or scripts) to be portable, it's best to stick with [POSIX specified features](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html).

Comment: @Wildcard one difference that always gets me is how to edit a file in place. In GNU sed you can just add a `-i` argument: `sed -i -e '...' $file` while in macOs you need an additional, separate empty argument: `sed -i '' -e '...' $file` I haven't yet been able to find a single invocation that will work in both.

Comment: @Tobia to portably edit a file in place, don’t use Sed at all; use “ex,” which is specified by POSIX.  I’ve written many answers using “ex” if you need examples.