# String.split not working with combination of delimiter {^

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to split the string with combination of `{^`

How to use combination of delimiter for splitting the string.

The sample data is :

```
String str = "0002{^000000000000001157{^000006206210015461{^PR{^ID{^62499{^";
```

Comment: Well what did you try?

Comment: Did str.split("\\{\\^") not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape `{` and `^` in your split Statement, because both are Special character in regex:

```
s.split("\\{\\^");
```

Comment: Thanks @Jens. I have a string with delimiter ^A(\001) delimiter. When i try to split the string using s.split("\\^A") i am getting the entire string( in linux environment). Because when i see the file with Cat command i cannot see the delimiter, but when i use cat -A filename, i can see ^A delimiter is there. please help me.

Comment: @Shankar `^A` is a control character. Note that is one character!! See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421478/how-to-remove-ctrl-a-characters-from-file-using-sed)

Comment: thanks for the info.. Could you please tell me how can i put that character in properties file (currently i tried with ^A -- which is two character), thats why its failing..

Comment: @Shankar As you can see in the link: "simply press Ctrl-v Ctrl-a"

Comment: In java i handled like s.split("\u0001") and it is working.. Thanks @Jens

Answer (score 4):

The delimiter passed to `String.split()` is a regex. As `{` and `^` are characters with special meaning within a regex, you need to escape them if you want to use them as literals:

```
String[] tokens = str.split("\\{\\^");
```

Answer (score 3):

split method in java takes an `regex` as an input.

so if you want to split the string using '{' and '^' then you need to do the following:

```
String str = "0002{^000000000000001157{^000006206210015461{^PR{^ID{^62499{^";

String[] splitted = str.split("\\{\\^");  //note \\ before { and ^
```

Comment: Sorry, I wrote almost the same answer, with seconds of difference. Yours was available first than mine, though, so I'm upvoting.

Comment: @Magnamag lol atcually ur answer appears to be 1min earlier than me. hope no hard feeling bud :)