# linux command to move part of string with non-printable character

Tags: substring, move, non-printable

I have binary log file with such similar lines which splitted by non-printable char "^A".

I see this symbol backlit white when I open file with command "less"

```
blah9234^Azzz123^A1=123
blah6344^Azzz123^A1=456
blah4555^Azzz123^A1=78912
```

I need convert it to:

```
zzz123^A1=123^Ablah9234
zzz123^A1=456^Ablah6344
zzz123^A1=78912^Ablah4555
```

so I need take first part

```
blah9234
```

add non-printable symbol ^A

```
^Ablah9234
```

and put it into the and of line

```
zzz123^A1=123^Ablah9234
```

to start I've tried to add ^A to the beginning of the line:

```
sed 's/^.*blah/^Ablah/' my.log > new.log
```

but it just adds '^' and 'A' and I got:

```
^Ablah9234^Azzz123^A1=123
```

and first ^A doesn't backlit white in less viewer.

Any advice's would be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: This should work `sed 's/^\(blah[^'$'\001'']\+\)'$'\001''\(.*\)$/\2'$'\001''\1/' my.log > new.log`

Comment: If you don't like multiple occurence of `$'\001'` you may use `sed $'s/^\\(blah[^\001]\\+\\)\001\\(.*\\)$/\\2\001\\1/' my.log > new.log`.

Comment: Or if your `sed` supports extended expression, try `sed -r $'s/^(blah[^\001]+)\001(.*)$/\\2\001\\1/' my.log > new.log`.

Comment: Pure bash `while IFS=$'\x01' read -r one two; do echo -e "${two}\x01${one}"; done < my.log > new.log`.

Comment: Or `awk -F$'\x01' 'BEGIN{OFS="\x01"}{print $2,$3,$1}' filename.txt`...

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

**You can do this:**

```
sed 's/^.*blah'$'\001''blah/' my.log > new.log
```

Or:

```
#get the value of the ^A control character
ctrlACode=$'\001'

#use it when we call sed
sed 's/^.*blah'"$ctrlACode"'blah/' my.log > new.log
```

<sub>To understand the second example, you need to understand [this.](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/escapingsection.html#STRQ)
Basically, `$'\0xx'` is equal to the control character that has that value in octal. For instance, `$'\000'` is the `NUL` control character. `$'\001'` is `^A`, the `SOH` control character, etc.</sub>

---

**An even easier way** is found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421478/how-to-remove-ctrl-a-characters-from-file-using-sed)

In this way, you type `ctrl-v` then `ctrl-a` to insert `^A`.