# How do you remove ^@ with sed?

Tags: sed, symbols

I am trying to parse some logs and there is a strange `^@` symbol in there. I can remove it in [vim](/questions/tagged/vim) by cutting that character and paste/searching for it, but how do I remove it in the bash command line automatically.

This doesn't work

```
sed 's/^@//'
```

Comment: that's likely not that string but the viewer showing you what is likely a null byte (value 0). see https://superuser.com/questions/287997/how-to-use-sed-to-remove-null-bytes ?

Comment: This answer is talking about ^A but you could use the same exact method for ^@ which is \x00  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15421538/2193968 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/13180336/2193968

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When faced with an unwanted byte in a text file represented by some other stand-in symbol, a tool like `hexdump` or `od` helps.  Try this:

1. Make a copy of the original file.
2. Remove everything in the copied file, except a line or two that includes  the mystery symbol.  Save the file.
3. To see what the byte *really* is, do:

   ```
   hexdump -v  -e '/1  "%_ad#  "' -e '/1 " _%_u\_\n"' file
   ```
4. From which listing find the hex code for the unwanted byte, (let's
   say it's *00*), and try:

   ```
   sed 's/\x00//' file
   ```

If that works, run the same `sed` line on the original file.